# Join three tables and show values in one query SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a shopping cart project and i have three tables - Orders - Ordersitems and products that i want to join them in a single query but i don't know how to do this, i want to show all values from all three tables, [see photo with tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRYI.jpg). here is what i have tried so far..

```
             $sql = "  SELECT o.*, 
                       oi.pid,
                       oi.orderid,
                       oi.pquantity,
                       c.cid,
                       c.catname,
                       p.name, 
                       p.description,
                       p.catid,
                       u.firstname,
                       u.lastname,
                       u.mobile,
                       u.email
                          FROM orders o,
                               orderitems oi,
                               products p,
                               usersmeta u,
                               category c
                         WHERE o.id    = oi.orderid
                           AND oi.pid  = p.id
                           AND o.uid   = u.uid
                           AND p.catid = c.cid
                         ORDER BY o.id DESC";
```

Comment: do you have error ?

Comment: I don't have any errors, it give's me some values but in the most incorect way..

Comment: what's the foreign key in your product table ?

Comment: What errors are you getting?
You actually have 4 tables to join - usersmeta is another. i would rewrite the query to only use left joins similar to how you've done the order items and see if that works. Since they are all explicitly linked to each other via surrogate primary keys I don't think cross joins are useful.

EDIT: if I understand your table layout properly, your left join on orderitems should be ```ON o.id=i.orderid```

Comment: Yes is 4, i missed out the usersmeta, i don't getting any errors

Comment: @Fido I'd recommend rewriting the query to be left joins with explicit ```ON``` clauses in the join and see how you go. (Also see my edit in previous comment)

Comment: I think i have done to have'it work, please see my update of code

Comment: i see i have different ID on first column it give's the id of the product, instead of order id

Comment: I think this is because ```SELECT * FROM...``` will include all 4 tables, and since all tables have a ID column MySQL doesn't know which ID you want, i'd recommend being more explicit in your SELECT like how your original question was.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to do this is:

```
select o.*, oi.*, p.*, u.*
  from orders o,
       orderitems oi,
       products p,
       usersmeta u
 where o.id = oi.orderid
   and oi.pid = p.id
   and o.uid = u.uid
 order by o.id desc;
```

Remember, it’s a good idea to specify only the name of the columns you need, such as:

```
select o.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, p.id as productid etc...
```

If you need that same query elsewhere, it might be a good idea to create a view.

Comment: Thanks for the support, with this i get this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: #1054 - Invalid column 'o.pid' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry, I changed the sql because had have an error. oi.pid = p.id... Please try again

Comment: The query is working but i see that the order id is different and is replaced with usersmeta id

Comment: It's because the tables have the same name for id columns, order and product.
the best approach here is use only the columns you need, like select u.firstname, u.email, o.id , p.id as productid, etc...